# Como concatenar valor de input à função?

Tags: javascript

Sendo novato em JS estou tentando concatenar o valor de um input a um valor aleatório que gerei, como se ao digitar o nome fosse gerado um nome de usuário randômico para a pessoa, pensei em salvar o nome numa função e então concatenar ambas, o problema é que não sei direito como fazer uma função que salve o valor digitado. Alguém disposto a dar uma luz?

Aqui vão as funções que tenho até agora, sendo `function receber_nome()` a que não consigo montar a lógica.

```
            function receber_nome()
        {

        }

        function gerar_string_aleatoria( tam, charset )
        {
            var serial = "";

            for( var i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
                serial += charset.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length) );

            return serial;
        }


        function gerar_serial()
        {
            return receber_nome() + gerar_string_aleatoria( 4, "0123456789" );
        }
```

Comment: Não precisa de uma função par pegar o nome, basta pegar o valor de um input por exemplo em que a pessoa digitou o nome e concatenar com o valor gerado.

Comment: @LeAndrade, vc diz usando um GetElementById no caso?

Comment: Isto mesmo Natã.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natã vou postar uma maneira bem simples de vc entender já que vc disse que não conhece muito de **Javascript**, pois as respostas dadas podem te confundir um pouco.

```js
function gerar_string_aleatoria( tam, charset ){
   var serial = "";

   for( var i = 0; i < tam; i++ ){
       serial += charset.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));   
    }
    return serial; 
}

function gerar_serial(){
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value; // pega o valor do input
  var p = document.getElementById('p'); // pega a tag p
  
  p.innerText = nome+ " - chave: "+ gerar_string_aleatoria( 4, "0123456789")+"\n"+ nome+" - chave: "+ gerar_string_aleatoria( 4, "0123456789"); 
  // escreve o resultado dentro da tag p
}
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" onblur="gerar_serial()">
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: Estava voltando e mexer nesse projeto e gostaria de saber como faço para inserir um looping de repetição nessa função gerar_serial. Por exemplo, gerar duas chaves. Tem como? Obrigado e desculpa incomodar novamente

Comment: Gerar duas chaves onde Natã, para a mesma pessoa?

Comment: Isto, sair algo como "Natã - chave: 0266; Natã - chave: 0148"

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, eu n tinha pensado nisso. Estava tentando colocar um for mas nunca me acertava hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Umas as coisas que tem que ter em mente é se acostumar a programar em inglês, entende.

```js
const serialGenetator = (parameters) => {
    let { name: n, size: t, characters: c } = parameters, s = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < t; i++) 
      s += c.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length));
    return n + s;
}

console.log(serialGenetator({
    name: "Douglas", //document.querySelector("element").value
    size: 10,
    characters: "0123456789"
}));
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a relação do "programar em inglês".

Comment: O motivo mais importante: inglês é o idioma internacional para código (e para documentações). Mais especificamente, o inglês americano é o padrão. Eu trabalho em uma empresa australiana e embora a Austrália siga a gramática britânica, o código que escrevemos segue a gramática americana (exemplo: “color” e não “colour”). Então se esse é o padrão mundial, por que não segui-lo?

Se você pretende um dia trabalhar fora do Brasil, potenciais empresas querendo te contratar vão querer ver seu código, mas não irão entender se estes estiverem em português.

Comment: Então procure deixar seus repositórios no Github com código e documentação em inglês.

Os comandos e palavras-chave de linguagens em programação são em inglês, então mesmo que você queria escrever em português, vai acabar ficando inevitavelmente uma mistura.

Algumas linguagens e frameworks estão preparados para entender o inglês em termos de semântica. Exemplo: o Ruby on Rails sabe que a tabela no banco de dados para um determinado model deve ser sempre o nome do model no plural. Ou seja,

Comment: ao ter um model Person, ele vai procurar uma tabela people.

Contribuições para projetos open-source devem ser em inglês. Eu sinceramente não conheço um projeto open-source famoso que não esteja em inglês.

Muitas empresas no Brasil já escrevem códigos em inglês. Então se eventualmente você começar a trabalhar em um dessas empresas, você terá que se adaptar de qualquer forma.

Acentos, “ç” e caracteres especiais não funcionam bem em todas as linguagens, fazendo que você tenha palavras escritas de forma incorreta se você as escrever em português.

Você treina e melhora seu inglês :)

Comment: "Umas as coisas que tem que ter em mente é se acostumar a programar em inglês, entende." Não. Isso vai depender muito do seu projeto, se você está desenvolvendo um projeto para uma empresa específica e brasileira, no qual todos seus funcionários, desenvolvedores e futuros desenvolvedores serão brasileiros, e o código não será aberto, não tem motivo algum para se desenvolver em inglês, o importante é o código ser o mais claro possível.

Comment: Sua resposta não responde a dúvida do colega também, visto que o que a dúvida dele é de como obter o valor do nome do usuário vindo do input, você simplesmente enviou um valor fixo no console.log

Comment: Caro Douglas, eu entendo a ótima intenção sobre programar com saber um pouco de inglês, eu concordo muito com boa parte disso, mas o foco do site é responder o problema da pergunta, vc postou o código, ótimo, agora poste uma explicação sobre o código, ai sua resposta será excelente provavelmente (se correta é claro), e sobre estudar ou não inglês caberia melhor como comentário (algo que vc ainda não pode fazer mas em breve poderá). Então por favor edite a resposta.

Comment: Complementando o que o @GuilhermeNascimento, o fato de termos um Stack Overflow em português é justamente atender os lusófonos. Se a pessoa precisasse depender do inglês (eu sei que ajuda, mas a idéia é não depender dele) bastaria o Stack Overflow original. Nosso papel aqui é justamente prover conteúdo para fazer essa ponte.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/180222)

Comment: Caro @CelsoMarigoJr "responde sim", só que precisa ser melhorada, entendo que é um comentario gerado automaticamente, mas provavelmente vc votou na fila de analise, acho que não é o caso de converter em comentário, dá para dizer de longe que o código funciona, só que não esta explicado. Reconsidere analisar um pouco mais antes de votar na fila de analise, isso é o mais saudável para o site.

Comment: Eu entendo o que quis dizer quanto a aprender a programar em inglês, mas como já dito, sou novato ainda no JavaScript e para pegar bem a lógica dele o português me é mais amigável, pretendo sim quando mais experiente passar aos códigos de padrão internacional. Sei que deu a dica com a melhor das intenções, portanto muito obrigado. Mas ainda pretendo seguir melhorando num ritmo mais confortável para mim mesmo, sem apressar as coisas. Forte abraço

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento "não responde não", o foco da dúvida da pergunta é como fazer a lógica da função `receber_nome()` que como base deve receber "o valor de um input" segundo a pergunta. E a resposta contém valores fixados não mostrando como obtê-los de forma dinâmica desse input.

Answer (score -1):

```
const input = document.getElementById("seu-input");

function gerar_string_aleatoria( tam, charset ) {
  var serial = "";

  for( var i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    serial += charset.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length) );

  return serial;
}


function gerar_serial(nome) {
  return nome + gerar_string_aleatoria( 4, "0123456789" );
}   

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode !== 13) return;
    console.log(gerar_serial(e.target.value))
})
```

Comment: A função está definida como `gerar_serial` e você está chamando como `gerarSerial`: ReferenceError.